# Full system analysis with UI

Tags: performance, administration

I recently started using [NewRelic](http://newrelic.com/) and now I'm wondering what other life-changing tools there are.

In specific, I'm working in Linux, and I was looking at my [RightScale](http://www.rightscale.com/) monitoring and saw that there was a spike in swap space usage. By the time I logged into the machine the swap was back to normal, so the only way for me to find out what used it would be to dig through the system logs and correlate by time.

Is there a NewRelic-like analytics for the entire system? With a sexy UI where I can click a metric, see the time-wise analysis, then click an area and see a list of processes, which users ran them, how much cpu/ram/swap/io/net they used etc?

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: @Sathya, Linux. I also modified my OP.